# Is "small-c conservative" or "capital-T Truth" redundant?

Tags: style, technique

In English speech, it's perfectly normal to refer to the capitalization of a term to clarify if it's a proper noun or not—"The party's new approach is small-c conservative", because the listener can't hear capitalisation.  But should one do this in writing, since the reader can already see the capitalisation? Is it redundant to write "small-c conservative" or "capital-t Truth", or just acceptable as part of pleonasm?

I have noticed that many respectable publications write out the redundant phrase, but the mere fact that this is often written out doesn't necessarily make it good writing....

For example, from [a recent article in *The Guardian*](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2021/jun/18/conservative-seat-england-middle-class-chesham-and-amersham-tories) (emphasis added):

> Not that long ago, people who lived in such places were largely assumed to be **small-c conservative**, and fond of the kind of lifestyle choices that went with that kind of outlook: golf, washing one’s car on a Sunday morning, keeping up with the proverbial Joneses.

Or from a [review article in the *New Republic*:](https://newrepublic.com/article/162533/whats-wrong-bob-dylans-biographers-clinton-heylin-review)

> If this penchant for fabulism is so deeply baked into Dylan’s DNA, then why should anyone reasonably expect that his private manuscripts or personal letters would adhere any more to the **capital-t Truth**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It's all about the statement, not letters:

When I met my wife, I described some of my friends as capital-C Catholics. My wife is a Catholic, but took it in good humor as I turned red.

The correct capitalization isn't what this is about. That's a matter for English class. This is about a different meaning entirely. Saying someone is a little-c conservative means they are not far-right conservative, or perhaps implies they are conservative in one area, but not in others. A big-C conservative is someone who conforms closely with all conservative values and is a bit fanatical/preachy about it.

Using this big-letter/small-letter emphasis is really about defining the direction of emphasis you want to place on a word. So a big-T truth is one that is all encompassing and strict, conceding the truth to their opponents even when it loses you an advantage. A little-t truth is implying someone says they follow the truth, but don't really take it that seriously. Little-t truth shouldn't get in the way of a really good argument.

So using this in writing isn't wrong, because it's not about the letter being capitalized or not. It's about the writer communicating a nuance of meaning to a word.

Comment: In some countries, there is a party called the Conservative Party.  Small c conservatives would have a conservative outlook but wouldn't necessarily be members of the Conservative Party.

Comment: @Ryan_L I didn't know the foreign context, but that totally fits with the theme of the answer. Thx!